# Add the "Only x Left" in product list page

Tags: product-list, stock-status

I have a custom theme template for my magento 1.9.1 and would like to add the "only X left" in my product list page. It is already in my product view page however I want it to show on every single product in the grid list page. 
How do I add to it?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than instantiating the model for each product rather do this.

Create a magento module, and add these bits to it.

In the module config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
            <class>your_module/observer</class>
            <method>addStockItemData</method>
        </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

In the module observer

```
<?php 
// observer
public function addStockItemData($observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addItemsToProducts($collection);
}
```

That will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to modify the theme's `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` file so that it included the required bits. That would be something like this under the grid mode and/or list mode depending on your site.

```
<?php $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
<?php if ($qty): ?>
    Only <?php echo $qty; ?> left
<?php else: ?>
    Out of Stock
<?php endif; ?>
```

However that would only work for simple products and would probably say all configurable, grouped, or bundled ones are out of stock so you'd want to modify it a bit more to work with that if you use configurable, grouped, or bundled products.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why I'm not getting the "out of stock" when my quantity is 0? It still says "Only 0.0000 left". Also I am getting a bunch of decimals. Do you know how can I get rid of the decimals?

Comment: Hi, I changed getQty to getStockQty and everything is good now. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: For the 0.0000 you could force it to an integer by doing `(int)` before the Mage::getModel part. It should force it to 0 and then that would trigger as false in PHP for the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem by editing `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php` file and added one line that seems to be missing in 1.9.1.0 `(->addAttributeToSelect('*'))`

```
$usedProducts = array();
$collection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
```